# cannot set capabilities of scanner through twain driver

Tags: vb.net

I have been working with TWAIN driver for few days. I have learnt how to connect to the scanner or get the working scanners connected to the machine. I am having a problem now, eventhough i get connected to the scanner, I am not able to set the capabilities from my application. The scanner scans using the capabilities that are set on it but not from my application. I have looked at the sample code given with twain pro but even that doesnt set the capabilities of the scanner. For example if the scanner is set to 300 dpi and I set 200dpi from my application, the scanner scans with 300 dpi. It gives me an error saying that the value given is out of range. Can anyone help me with this. I am using vb.net.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's very difficult to help you, since you didn't post any code that shows what you're trying that didn't work. Please edit your post and add the relevant code. (You can format it as code in the editor by selecting the code and then using the toolbar button with the image like `{}` or pressing Ctrl+K, or simply indent the block by 4 or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your scanner supports 200 dpi. You can either read the user manual of your scanner, or negotiate with the capability ICAP_XRESOLUTION to list all the supported values.